# If $x\varpropto \dfrac{1}{y}$ and $y\varpropto \dfrac{1}{z}$, prove that $z \varpropto x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x\varpropto \dfrac{1}{y}$ and $y\varpropto \dfrac{1}{z}$, prove that $z \varpropto x$.

$x\varpropto \dfrac{1}{y} \iff x=\dfrac{m}{y} $ and $y\varpropto \dfrac{1}{z} \iff y=\dfrac{m}{z}$.

Hence $x=\dfrac{m}{\dfrac{m}{z}}=z$, or $x=z$.

My question is $z \varpropto x$ means $x=mz$, but I'm only able to show $x=z$. So how do I prove the $m$ exists or is it just by definition always existing in variations? Thanks.

Comment: You have written $x=\frac m y$ and $y=\frac m z$. You cannot use the same $m$ in both places.

Comment: If your proof was valid then you would have proved too much not too little.  $x = z$ is proportional, a very particular case.  However, the proof is not correct for the reason that geetha mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the same $m$ for both relationships. Instead write $x=\frac{m_1}{y}$ and $y=\frac{m_2}{z},$ so $x=\frac{m_1}{m_2}z, $ as We want to show.

Comment: Can you explain why the $m$ has to be different? I can see that $x,y$ and $y,z$ are different variables, but I really don't understand explicitly why $m$ needs to be different. Thank you.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson I recommend you don't call it $m$ in general, but rather "the proportionality ratio". So your interrogation becomes "Can you explain why the proportionality ratio has to be different?". And in this case, it's not so much "the proportionality ratio has to be different" but rather "we don't know that the two proportionality ratios are the same". And since we don't know that they are the same, we do ***not*** use the same symbol to represent them.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson I recommend you review the intuitive definition of proportionality, not just the formal one with this $m$ but what it means intuitively. Imagine $x$ is a number of pies, and $y$ is a price in euros. Then I tell you: When $x=2$, $y = 24$. When $x=3$, $y = 36$. When $x=5$, $y=60$. When $x=100$, $y=1200$. What do you conclude about $x$ and $y$?